# ES6 Destructuring in Class constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

This may sound ridiculous but bear with me. I wonder if there is support on the language level to destructure object into class properties in constructor, e.g.

```
class Human {
    // normally
    constructor({ firstname, lastname }) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.fullname = `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}`;
    }

    // is this possible?
    // it doesn't have to be an assignment for `this`, just something
    // to assign a lot of properties in one statement
    constructor(human) {
        this = { firstname, lastname };
        this.fullname = `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want `fullname` to retain changes in `firstname` and `lastname`, use a getter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: @Jan right thanks. Sorry it was a bad example. I just want to demonstrate that after `firstname` and `lastname` there are more initialization if that makes sense.

Comment: `this` cannot be assigned to - in ES5 never, in ES6 the only thing that changes its "value" is `super()`. But to assign properties on it, see the duplicate.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You cannot assign to `this` anywhere in the language.

One option is to merge into `this` or other object:

```
constructor(human) {
  Object.assign(this, human);
}
```

Comment: Cheers. I know we can't assign to this but was hoping for something similar. I was very keen on using destructuring because it has a clear schema, i.e. telling me which properties are being assigned. But anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Or maybe you need this? constructor({ firstname, lastname }) {
        Object.assign(this, {firstname, lastename});
        this.fullname = `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}`;
    }

Comment: @r03 have u tried that solution  ?it actually works ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: There's no *destructuring* in this answer..

Comment: this remove intellisence in the  VScode ide.

Comment: No typing are saved.