# Sugared typescript class constructor that accepts itself?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm reading in `Todo` instances from a CSV file and Papaparse does not do dynamic conversion on dates so I can drop the object into its own constructor to do the conversion:

```
class Todo {
    public dueDate:Date;
    ....
    constructor(todo:Todo) {
       this.dueDate = new Date(todo.dueDate);
       ...
    }
}
```

Is there exists a more sugared approach to initializing the properties via the constructor

Comment: I don't believe so, but you could do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413025/es6-destructuring-in-class-constructor

Comment: I tried `Object.assign` but it does not do the date conversion - Just assigns the same strings that are on the constructor object ...

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding your question.. I think your asking how do you initialize values on the constructor without specifying each value, in which case `Object.assign` is what your looking for. It will not handle any additional logic you want to perform on those properties but you could do it in the assign... `Object.assign(this, todo, {dueDate: new Date(todo.dueDate)})`

Comment: So you are mistyping the constructor parameter?  It doesn't accept a `Todo` at all, but something like `{[K in keyof Todo]: Todo[K] extends Date ? string : Todo[K]}` (meaning `{dueDate: string}` in your stripped-down example)

Comment: @jcatz -  No the constructor parameter takes a parameter that is an instance of the `Todo` class.  Although it's not a valid instance, because the date is a string.  So within the constructor the date string is wrapped in a new `Date` object.  This way the instance can be validated using an `@IsDate` validation annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Use TypeScripts auto properties, constructor parameters become properties with protected, public and private prefixes.

```
class Todo {
    constructor(public dueDate:Date) { }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can do that because I'm annotating the properties with validation constraints like `@IsDate dueDate`.  IIUC that means we can't place the properties within the constructor?

Comment: Why would you validate with model decorators? Should validation not be a form concern?

Comment: Using this library ... that I built ... gotta eat my own dog food ... https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/validator

Comment: These are CSV records being read in ... mostly business data ... like purchase orders etc.  The Todo class illustration was just to keep it simple.  I mainly need the date conversion, as papaparse converts numbers and booleans.